custom route in local network between two routers subnet with shared VPN
Setup described on image Miro: network setup. I use second router for one VPN on multiple childs. Connection created in Windows, because of multiple different VPNs (OpenVPN, Outline, WireGuard etc.)
Windows 2022 DC 21H2 (also need same config on Windows 2008 EE R2) with default configuration, no additional services enabled.
Is it possible to access from VM_1 subnet (192.168.1.0) to laptops subnet (192.168.2.0) in both ways?
I tried static routes in Windows (PC) and second router, but it doesn't work (((
on router 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.137.1(or 2)
in Windows(PC) 192.168.2.100 255.255.255.0 192.168.137.1(or 2)
many thanks for help
